# How to test performance of a multithreaded, client-server environment

Tags: server, performance-testing

I am busy writing a server application and a client application.  The server application is multithreaded, meaning that multiple client requests can be handled at the same time.  However, some of the client requests need to be sequenced because they modify the same underlying data.

My scrum tester is now asking me what the best way is to test this environment.
Are there any type of benchmarks (in the literature or from practical experience) that can be used?  For example

- real time between sending user request and getting the answer
- CPU time spent by the server handling a bunch of client requests
- ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Some of Performance metrics to be monitored.

```
How many users can your website handle concurrently?
How fast will your application respond to the user actions?
How often will users get errors and need to reconnect?
Will your website respond correctly to a stress load?
Will it return to normal operation after peak load times?
```

What i would suggest is to go through reporting option of any performance tools. It would fairly give lot many performance metrics.
Example : [loadtestingtool](https://www.loadtestingtool.com/help/html-report.shtml)

**If you are looking for any tools for this :**

For multi-threaded performance testing use **Apache Jmeter** tool.
For more details use [this URL.](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

You need to use http rest APIs and created equivalent jmeter request and anlayse the server performance.

I would suggest go for tools WAPT, it provides record and play with sophisticated reporting.

Suggestion would be go

Comment: the question is about the what, not the how

Comment: You are right. question is on how. I agree.  Following any load tool reporting options. Many performance metrics can be figured out.